# Error when creating Linear layout in java and passing its id it to viewpager adapter. Throwing RESOURCE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, android-layout, exception

Here is my source code. Here I am creating Layouts and adding text view to layouts. I am putting all layout ids in an arraylist and passing it to customviewpager adapter.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);


        LinearLayout rlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rlayout.setId(R.id.rid);
        rlayout.setLayoutParams(rParams);
        TextView rtext = new TextView(this);
        rtext.setText("hello");
        rtext.setId(R.id.rtext);
        rtext.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rlayout.addView(rtext);

        LinearLayout blayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        blayout.setId(R.id.bid);
        blayout.setLayoutParams(bParams);

        TextView btext = new TextView(this);
        btext.setText("helo");
        btext.setId(R.id.btext);
        btext.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        blayout.addView(btext);

        LinearLayout glayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams gParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        glayout.setId(R.id.gid);

        TextView gtext = new TextView(this);
        gtext.setText("hello");
        gtext.setId(R.id.gtext);
        glayout.setLayoutParams(gParams);
        gtext.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        glayout.addView(gtext);

        arrayList.add(0,R.id.bid);
        arrayList.add(1,R.id.rid);
        arrayList.add(2,R.id.gid);



        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this,arrayList));
    }

    }
```

Here is the View pager adapter.Here I am receiving the resource Ids and inflating the layouts and casting it to viewgroup. But I am getting resource not found exception.

```
    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList <Integer> viewList;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList arrayList) {
        mContext = context;
        viewList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) 
    inflater.inflate(viewList.get(position), collection, false);
        collection.addView(layout);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object 
    view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }


}
```

Comment: What you're doing there doesn't really make sense. Why are you trying to inflate `View`s you've already created dynamically? Inflation is for creating `View`s from layout XML.

Comment: But how can I get layout from their id to add it viewgroup collection.

Comment: You don't, really. Not like that. If that's how you want to create the `View`s for your `ViewPager`, then you can just pass the Adapter an `ArrayList<View>`.

Comment: okay. thanks. I will try

Comment: worked.thanks. But not ArrayList<View>, instead I did ArrayList<ViewGroup>

Comment: `ViewGroup` is a subclass of `View`. An `ArrayList<View>` would work just as well.